# How to get each table td text in AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs

I created a table and populated all `<tr>` values using `ng-repeat` and it worked well. I wanted to get all texts for an element with a class name "hours" within the populated `<td>`, in JQuery I just use `$(".hours").each();`, how do I do that in AngularJS?

Here is my HTML table below:

```
<tr class="hideID" ng-repeat="td in tableVals | orderBy : 'Day'" db-id="{{td.id}}">
    <td class="datesCell">{{td.Day}}</td>
    <td class="clientz">{{td.Client}}</td>
    <td class="depat">{{td.Department}}</td>
    <td class="activity">{{td.Activity}}</td>
    <td class="hours">{{td.Hours}}</td>
    <td class="billHours">{{td.Bill_Hours}}</td>
    <td class="billKM">{{td.Bill_KM}}</td>
    <td class="kmT contEdit">{{td.KM_Traveled}}</td>
    <td class="rm contEdit">{{td.Remarks}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Depends where you need it. You can just do in your javascript (controller probably): `var hoursArray = tableVals.map(function(t) { return t.Hours; });`. But you should probably explain where and why you need the hours

Comment: Ok, well i created a separate controller for calculating Total number of hours... and display it in a span element somewhere within a page

Comment: Then I would create a variable and display that one: `$scope.totalHours = $scope.tableVals.reduce(function(a,b){ return a + b['Hours']; }, 0);` and display it in a span: `<span>Total: {{ totalHours }}</span>`

Comment: Thanks a lot sir :)